# I want to create .dmg file from my source file on ubuntu so that I can distribute it on mac?

Tags: application-development, macosx, custom-distributions, custom-installer

Is there a way to create .dmg file from my source file, from command line, or is there any software available which will allow me to roll out my software on mac OS as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't yet.

The first step to get this working at all, though, would be to create an Mac OS installer for the Ubuntu SDK, so that apps can run there at all.

Answer (score 0):

It should be technically possible now, but you'll still need a Mac because it still requires the macOS platform SDK from Xcode, and only Mac owners are licensed to use that.

(Same way cross-compiling for Windows with MSVC ABI using LLVM requires the platform SDK files from Visual C++. There isn't a Mac equivalent to MinGW yet.)

I don't have a Mac, but the process I'm told other people have found success with is:

1. Use a cross-compiling toolchain like [osxcross](https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross) to build your binary.
2. Follow the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286419/how-to-build-a-dmg-mac-os-x-file-on-a-non-mac-platform) to use either `mkfs.hfsplus` or `genisoimage` to generate an uncompressed HFS filesystem with a `.dmg` extension.
3. (optional) Use [libdmg-hfsplus](https://github.com/fanquake/libdmg-hfsplus) to convert your uncompressed `.dmg` to `compressed`.dmg`.

Generally, the more recommended approach these days is just to find a CI service which has paid for Mac hardware and gives out free accounts to open-source projects and have your CI service build the DMGs.